# Is it possible to open a pipe-based filehandle which prints to a variable in perl?

Tags: perl, file-io

I know I can do this,

```
------
open(F,">",\$var);
print F "something cool";
close(F);
print $var;
------
```

or this,

```
 

open(F, "| ./prog1 | ./prog2 > tmp.file");
print F "something cool";
close(F);
```

but is it possible to combine these?  The semantics of what I'd like to do should be clear from the following,

```
open(F,"|./prog1 | ./prog2", \$var);
print F "something cool";
close(F);
print $var;
```

however the above clearly won't work.

A few minutes of experimenting and googling seems to indicate that this is not possible, but I'd like to know if I'm stuck with using the `` to capture the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I actually wanted to do is not possible in perl.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your goal a couple of ways.  None of them quite as easy as piling extra stuff into `open`.

You can use [IO::Tee](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IO::Tee) or other similar module, or even write your own `tee` style subroutine:

```
my $var ='';

open my $vh, '>', \$var or die "oh noes $!\n";
open my $ph, '| ./prog1 | ./prog2' or die "Uh oh $!\n";

my @handles = ($vh, $ph);

print_to_all( \@handles,
    "I like cheese.\n",
    "I like teas.\n",
);

print $var;    

sub print_to_all {
     my $handles = shift;

     for my $h ( @$handles ) {
         print $h @_;
     }

     return;
}
```

Another way to go would be to make a [tied variable](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/tie.html) that acts as a file handle and a scalar at the same time.

Comment: In the above example $var will end up just containing the original strings, while the result of the pipe command will be printed to STDOUT.  I was curious about getting the pipe command output directly into $var, and I don't think this will do the trick.  I tried running this code with my own prog1, prog2, but at the end it ends up with $var containing only the original concatenated input strings.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is open the file handle as you have, read the contents to a variable, append whatever you want to that variable and then [set the environment variable as is stated here](http://www.devdaily.com/perl/edu/qanda/plqa00014/) to the full string that you have just generated.

You were almost there and I hope that helps. :)

Comment: hmm, i know i can slurp the file i want to feed to the pipe into a variable and then send it all at once - think this is what you are suggesting, right? but i want to do this line by line which i guess is impossible.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know a way to do it line by line.

Comment: To do this line by line use a `while` loop to process the input handle on a line by line basis and print to the output handle.  `print OUT $_ while <IN>;`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is not possible as perl does not support 'pipe at both ends'.  More info here,

http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html

Corion over at perlmonks.org answered this for me.

Comment: Did you post to SOPW or ask in chatterbox?  If SOPW, please post a link.

Comment: I am frequently surprised by how small the set of things that are not possible in Perl is. This is another example of something that is not not possible: see daotoad's suggestion for a tied variable.

Comment: @mobrule I'm fairly certain at this point that this is not possible, at least not the way that I'd like to do it, and the reason I was given was basically that this would have a high chance of producing buffering issues.  I tried daotoad's example and it does not work (see comment).  Anyway this isn't a dig against perl - which I quite love, I was just curious.

Answer (score 0):

- `IPC::Open2` might do the trick, see `man perlipc`. More likely than not, however, you will deadlock your program that way. It's safe though, as long as the data in the pipe is smaller than PIPE_BUF (on Linux 4096), only written once, and the write-side immediately closed after writing the data and before reading the result.
- You might try to rewrite your program to fork such that you end up with: `YourProg | ./prog1 | ./prog2 | YourProgForked`.
- On modern Linux you can use /dev/shm to host a temporary file entirely in virtual memory.